# How to get background color of div?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a `div` I want when user clicks on this div the background color of div should be display in alert box using jquery only ?

Comment: What does "jQuery only" mean?

Comment: @SLaks No JavaScript. Just jQuery :P

Comment: @alex: you... are aware that jQuery IS JavaScript, right?

Comment: Now you should accept someone's answer, because these answers are correct.

Comment: @Chris [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humour) :D

Comment: Ah sarcasm. Yeah I've heard of it, who says I haven't....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    var $c=$(this).css("background-color");
    alert($c);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, I mean, why use `$` for a variable name? I think it could be confusing.

Comment: @Renesis: I specify `$` for jquery-objects, to help determine easily where the jquery object and where it is not. Not in such cases though (when we have just a string).

Answer (score 6):

```
$('div').click(function() {
   alert($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3SpV4/).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the color like this:

```
$('div#test').css('background-color'); // returns RGB
```

and display it after click like that:

```
$('div#test').click(function(){
    alert($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xWkDW/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#divBack{
  background-color:#00FFCC;
}
<div id="divBack">click to Get my background</div>
$('#divBack').click(function() {
    alert($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

I have created bin for you please check this link http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpc1