# How do I use jQuery to return the current state of my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, colors

```
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click',()=>{
div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color)+10;
var c = (div.dataset.color%256)*100;
div.style.background = 'rgb(0,'+c+',0)';
});

#myDiv {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000000;
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If I am using this code for individuals to choose a color, how do I use jquery to return the current state of the color picker? Meaning, if a person was clicking through until they found the color they wanted, what can i do to log the selection that they decide on? Is there a button I can use to select the color and then output that selection into an excel file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get background color of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025197/how-to-get-background-color-of-div)

Comment: may be useful. https://jsfiddle.net/guebbb7t/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to select the `div` in jQuery and use the [css function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to retrieve the value that you are looking for.

```
$("#myDiv").css("background-color");
```